# How does Blazor hijack the Browser-Back button?

Tags: browser, signalr, blazor-server-side

Blazor-Server apps use the SignalR circuit.
I can somewhat understand how there is JS that change events happening from the DOM, so instead of sending a new HTTP GET request the framework manipulates the DOM and displays the new blazor page.

But how is it even possible that the circuit is still active and working on page back button? This is a BROWSER FEATURE, not some html element, which can be changed, right? Would it not be a security issue if the browser back button behavior can be manipulated in different ways?
Not firing a new HTTP GET request on page back seems pretty hacky. Wouldn't that allow for malicious websites to do the same? Can websites access the last page visited with that??

How does the browser "know" that the last page should also use the same websocket circuit?
Is it then possible to tell the browser that it should establish a websocket on a past page, that didn't even have any before (would seem like a security risk)?

How does the back button differ from hitting "enter" in the address bar (which will always cut and establish a new circuit)?

Is the back button exactly the same as calling JS history.back() ?